# Multiple Task.Run not waiting/running properly

Tags: c#, task

I'm trying to optimize a heavy process with some tasks, but it seems that after the first iteration it skips the `ProcessQueue` method run.

```
private void ImportSheet(Excel.Worksheet Data)
{
    this._ImportedSlurry = new ConcurrentQueue<AnalizedDataDTO>();
    this._LastRowReached = false;
    this._CurrentRow = this._FirstRow;
    while(!this._LastRowReached)
    {
        AnalizedDataDTO ImportedRow = this.ValidateRow(Data, _CurrentRow);

        Task task1 = Task.Run(() => ProcessQueue(Enumerable.Range(this._CurrentRow, 50).ToArray(),Data));
        Task task2 = Task.Run(() => ProcessQueue(Enumerable.Range(this._CurrentRow+50, 50).ToArray(),Data));

        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
        this._CurrentRow += 100;
    }
}

private void ProcessQueue(int[] range, Excel.Worksheet Data)
{
    for (int i = range.First(); i < range.Length; i++)
    {
        AnalizedDataDTO ImportedRow = this.ValidateRow(Data, i);
        if (ImportedRow == null)
        {
            this._LastRowReached = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            this._ImportedSlurry.Enqueue(ImportedRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "after the first iteration it skips the ProcessQueue", does it? How do you know? Does `IImportedRow == null` on the second task. If so then your loop would only run once.

Comment: To me it looks like your `this._CurrentRow += 50;` should be `this._CurrentRow += 100;` as you're processing 100 items between the two tasks. That may not be relevant, but it seems worth fixing...

Comment: @JonSkeet Fixed, and yes, that wasn't relevant to the problem.
@BenRobinson I can know it because debugging `_LastRowReached` is never `true` but it keeps looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your for-loop, to be specific its if-condition.

You should either iterate over `range`, i.e.

```
foreach (var i in range)
```

or iterate over an index, i.e.

```
foreach (var idx = 0; idx < range.Length; idx++)
{
    var i = range[idx];
```

---

For example assume that `this._CurrentRow == 100`, then your version of the for loop would look like:

```
for (int i = 100 /* range.First() */; i < 50 /* range.Length */; i++)
```